# Hide a property on an OData object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

Assuming you have code like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder { Namespace = "Blah" };
var foo = builder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foo");
var bar = builder.EntitySet<Foo>("Bar");
```

(notice they're both of type `Foo`, but with different endpoint names (Foo/Bar).

I know that I can hide properties by doing this:

```
foo.EntityType.Ignore(f => f.Baz);
```

However, that also hides the property when accessing it through the Bar endpoint. (Presumably because it's hidden from the underlying type itself)

Is there some way to hide a property only for the individual endpoints and not from the underlying type itself?

EDIT:

I've also tried, after using `EntityType.Ignore()`, to add things back using the various `Has*` methods, e.g. `foo.HasManyBinding(f => f.Baz)`, but trying to access the property at this point gives the following error:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58799/odata/Foo(42)/Baz'.","innererror":{
      "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want different objects for different entity sets you'd need to define a `Bar` type that is distinct from the `Foo` type (or perhaps related via inheritance). If both entity sets really need to represent the same type, then is simply ignoring the property in `Foo` scenarios practical for your scenario?

Comment: It can be done, it would just be "cleaner", metadata-wise, for the "other" type not to have the property. The thing here is that Users and Companies are both stored as users in the underlying data model, but I'd like to have Companies as one endpoint and Users as another, and so it makes no sense for the Users type to have a "ChildUsers" property, e.g., nor does it make sense for the Company to have a "Company" property. So yeah, it's not the end of the world, it just feels wrong.

Comment: I guess if you can squint and say that a Company is a User (I'll leave politics out of this ;)) then inheritance may work for you - as long as you can abstract away the differences between a Company and a User in way that makes sense. I think that's really your only option to keep things "clean".